# Which kernel function manages balancing the RB-tree of the linux CFS?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, scheduler, cfs

From what I have understood so far about the Linux CFS is that scheduling entities are indexed by their virtual runtime (`vruntime`) inside the RB-tree.

The scheduler regularly updates this `vruntime` by calling the `update_curr` function which basically increase the vruntime value of the current running entity.

What I don't understand is how does the scheduler keeps the RB-tree always well ordered. The `update_curr` function increases the value of `vruntime` but does not seem to check whether the entity should be moved back into the right of RB-tree. Which function performs this check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Ahmed is right about `update_curr`, I was still confused about the fact the tree could be unbalanced between the moment vruntime is updated and the eventual call to `resched_curr`. As a matter of fact, it turns out that the task that is currently scheduled **is not part of the tree**.

It is removed from the tree in `set_next_entity(cfs_rq_of(se), se);` which is called when `pick_next_task_fair` is invoked. So the tree is always balanced and the only function performing the balancing are `enqueue_entity` and `dequeue_entity`

Answer (score 0):

update_curr doesn't just increase the value of `vruntime` it also calls `account_cfs_rq_runtime` which in turn eventually calls `resched_curr` which will fix the RB-tree (eventually)

Comment: Does this mean that the tree is not fixed until the ```resched_curr``` call?

Comment: right... but resched_curr is guaranteed to be called.